# Live Audio Streaming from Webpage

Tags: java, swing, audio, stream, audio-streaming

I am working on a Swing radio project in which the user types in a URL, and my Java Program will take live audio from the given link and play it live for the user. The issue is that the user may type in a live radio URL that may not be formatted as an .mp3/.wav/.aiff file, it could just be a website-link that plays audio when launched through an online media player, such as in BBC Radio One (http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/player/bbc_radio_one).

I have tried the [Java Sound API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-139508.html), however, it only supports URLs that are directed to music files (ex. foo.com/bar.wav/). The sound API cannot support URLs such as http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/player/bbc_radio_one because they are not audio files. If you were to go to the BBC Radio One link, you would find that it automatically starts playing live audio. That live audio is what I'd like to have played in my Java program.

On StackOverflow, I had found people who had similar issues to mine, but they were using .mp3/.wav/.aiff/ etc URLs, which is good, but does not work for me.

I had also found a page on [Program Creek](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream) that had shown multiple methods of playing audio through URLs. I had tried to use many of the examples on there, but none of them would work because of either the format of my URL or Stream Errors. For instance, I had slightly modified one of the methods (from example 4 on [Program Creek](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream)):

```
 /**
 * Plays the audio file specified in the 'url' parameter.
 * @param url URL for Audio Loading
 */
public void play(final String url) {
    try {
        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(url);
        InputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        AudioInputStream ain = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(buf);
        AudioFormat format = ain.getFormat();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
        Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        clip.open(ain);
        clip.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And I'd get the following error ([here](https://pastebin.com/WAcUtFSh)) when I'd give the BBC Radio One URL (http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/player/bbc_radio_one) for it to play.

Is there any way I could either get rid of this IOException error, or use a non-audio-file URL to receive a live audio stream a different way? Would you be able to lead me into the right path to figuring this out?

Thanks.

Comment: What is it you think this has to do with Swing? Also, do you have permission from the BBC to embed their content in your app.? Why not just `Desktop.getDesktop().browse(theURL)` instead?

Comment: @AndrewThompson This project has nothing to do with Swing, I just thought I'd mention it to give you a better sense of my project. I had used BBC as an example of a link that is not a .mp3/.wav/.aiff link. And could you please elaborate on your response "`Desktop.getDesktop().browse(theURL)`" ?

Comment: *"could you please elaborate"* Sure. I could.